# horizontal scrolling function

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application that is suppose to have scrolling function on the tab layout. But I do not really know the way to implement it, can anyone help? I intend to add in more tabs at the top on the page and then scroll through the tabs horizontally.

java code

```
 import android.app.TabActivity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.res.Resources;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TabHost;
 import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

 public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 Resources ressources = getResources(); 
 TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

 // Livingroom tab
 Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, livingroomActivity.class);
 TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
 .newTabSpec("livingroom")
 .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.Living))
 .setContent(intentLiving);

 // dadnmom tab
 Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, dadmomActivity.class);
 TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
 .newTabSpec("Dadmom")
 .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_apple_config))
 .setContent(intentdadmom);

 // myroom tab
 Intent intentWindows = new Intent().setClass(this, myroomActivity.class);
 TabSpec tabSpecWindows = tabHost
 .newTabSpec("myroom")
 .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_windows_config))
 .setContent(intentmyroom);

 // kitchen room tab
 Intent intentBerry = new Intent().setClass(this, kitchenActivity.class);
 TabSpec tabSpecBerry = tabHost
 .newTabSpec("kitchen")
 .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_blackberry_config))
 .setContent(intentkitchen);

 // add all tabs 
 tabHost.addTab(tabSpecliving);
 tabHost.addTab(tabSpecdadmom);
 tabHost.addTab(tabSpecmyroom);
 tabHost.addTab(tabSpeckitchen);

 //set Windows tab as default (zero based)
 tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
 }

 }
```

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:padding="5dp">
 <TabWidget
 android:id="@android:id/tabs"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 <FrameLayout
 android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:padding="5dp" />
 </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HorizontalScrollView` for your `TabWidget` in xml

Eg.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Use `<HorizontalScrollView>` in the xml to achieve horizontal scrolling